# shell script executing on remote host

Tags: command-line, scripts

I want to run `testcmd.sh` on remote host (Testhost) using the following command:

```
ssh test@Testhost 'bash -s' < /test/testcmd
```

But I get the below error :

```
!!!!!Running MASTERCMD!!!!!
bash: line 31: /test/PROCESSLIST: No such file or directory
```

I dont want to have the `PROCESSLIST` file placed locally on the Testhost. How can I overcome this?

---

Cat Testcmd is below:

```
echo "!!!!!Running MASTERCMD!!!!!"

RC=0
while read proc; do
        if (( 0 == $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -c /test/$proc) )); then
                echo "!!!!! $proc down on  TU  !!!!!"
                RC=1
         else
           echo "!!!!!! $proc is still running on  TU!!!!!"
        fi
#echo "Not checked"

done < /test/PROCESSLIST
```

Comment: Have you tried prefixing your whole command with `cat /test/PROCESSLIST | `? At first glance that may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the script `/test/testcmd` runs on the remote host it needs a `/test/PROCESSLIST` file in the remote host, in the same way it needs it in the local host (`while [...]; do [...]; done < /test/PROCESSLIST`).

That's what the error is about, but going further the script is going to break even when fixed this, since it also needs multiple `/test/$proc` files, whose actual names are determined at run-time based on `/test/PROCESSLIST`'s content (`if [...] grep -c /test/$proc [...]; then [...]; else [...]; fi`).

In the end, you need to copy your local `/test` folder to the remote host:

```
scp -r /test test@Testhost:/test
```

However you'll very likely need to be root on the remote host in order to be able to copy it to `/`:

```
scp -r /test root@Testhost:/test
```

However root might be disabled / have no password set on the remote host; so a workaround would be to copy the folder in `test`'s home directory and to copy it to `/` using `sudo`:

```
scp -r /test test@Testhost:~/test
ssh -t test@Testhost sudo mv ~/test /test
```

Comment: @kos...i have added scp command in the script and it doesnt work when called form the script but when i execute the command it works.    scp  /test/PROCESSLIST test@Testhost:/tmp/PROCESSLIST

Comment: @canonical It doesn't work because the script it's executed on the remote host, while the `scp` command I posted is meant to be executed from the local host *once* in order to copy the necessary files to the remote host. In fact it works because you've copied the files already, you should remove the `scp` command from the script

Comment: @canonical Also I see you didn't accept any answer to your questions so far. Consider accepting answers if they worked for you and to upvote them as well along with any other useful answer you've received to your questions; accepting is how you can indicate that an answers worked for you, while upvoting is how you can indicate whether an answer was useful, and of course they are both a way to give reputation to the user who posted it.